# How to perform dot annotation for crowd counting in a image file using Matlab?

Tags: image-processing

I have some crowd images having more than 300 people in each image. I want to label each person(i.e. head) with dot annotation such that coordinate of each dot(x,y) is saved in a .mat file. I hope there is something in Matlab for this task.

Answer (score 2):

The Viola Jones algorithm does the face detection for you using the Cascade Object Detector.

```
%Read the image
x= imread('C:\~\crowd.jpeg');
x=rgb2gray(x);

%Face detection
faceDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector;
bboxes = step(faceDetector,x);
```

The first two columns of bboxes gives the (x,y) coordinates of the faces detected

If you want to label the people in the picture:

```
x1 = bboxes(:,1) %x co-ordinates
x2 = bboxes(:,2) %y co-ordinates
figure;
imshow(x);
for i=1:size(x1,1)
    plot(x1(i),x2(i),'*');
end
```

Saving the data in a .mat format:

```
save('dot.mat','x1','x2');
```

Accessing the data:

```
load('dot.mat');
```

To save data points from a given image, you can use `ginput` method. First read the image and then use `[x,y] = ginput(n)` where n is the number of points you need to save.

Comment: An algorithmic approach for face detection will contain errors in it's (x,y) co-ordinates. Basically, I want a ground truth labeller, a gui based software where I can annotate each person's head by a dot. In Matlab's existing Ground truth Labeller app and Image Labeller app I didn't found any functionality for dot annotation.

Comment: So, you want to save mouse-click co-ordinates of the faces?  If that is the case, I have added a small comment at the end of my answer.